# Selection tool height and width setting disappeared in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Before when I used the Selection tool I had some boxes in the top toolbar where I could set x and y positioning and width/height. It somehow has disappeared. How can I get this feature back in y toolbar?

Here's an image of how my toolbar currently looks:
[image: selection tool illustrator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must've gotten hidden accidentally.

Click on the 3 lines drop-down on the far right [image] and make sure that *Shapes* is checked. [image]

---

> As [John pointed out](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104017/selection-tool-setting-height-and-width-disappeared-in-ilustrator/104018?noredirect=1#comment153591_104018) that the OP may have actually been reffering to the *Transform Panel*

If you are trying to *move* the shape, you would just have to click on *Transform* and that will open a panel where you can set the X and Y position of the path, you can also resize it from within that panel

[image: transform button]

[image: transform panel]

Comment: Don't you men "transform"?

Comment: @JohnBurgess no, that would be to *move* the path. Shapes is the one the OP is looking for (you can see that she already has Transform there)

Comment: I still believe what they want is to see the transform panel.

Comment: @שelz thank you very much for your care. but shape is checked.  there were before at top but right now its disappear

Comment: @שelz and no I just want to set width and height and x and y for the shape, the problem solved I found transform box. thank you very very much

Comment: woow yes exactly transform what I need, it was there on top before why it goes on transform button. thank you very very much  also @JohnBurgess

Comment: @JohnBurgess how could I checked your help?

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh don't worry about giving me specific credit, the answer has been edited to have correct information, so mark it as a correct answer.